# How do I know the Marketing Cloud Edition, which I am logged into?

Tags: marketing-cloud, editions

Do anyone know a way (say using MID) to know the Marketing Cloud Edition which my company/org currently using. I am aware there are different Editions available as below.

- Basic
- Pro
- Corporate
- Enterprise

---

[image: I am seeing the values as "CONNECT", I was looking for values like Basic, Pro,Corporate, Enterprise]

I am seeing the values as "CONNECT", I was looking for values like Basic, Pro,Corporate, Enterprise... as in your screenshots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information is sent in an API-response the background when accessing the Marketing Cloud dashboard. So you can either check the network tab of your browser's developer tools or use the Google Chrome extension ["Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Developer Tools"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-marketing-clou/bkmmmgaljahinmpijhdggabkdngpadbn?hl=en-US).

> **Instance Info**
>   If you open this extension and visit the Marketing Cloud Dashboard, basic information about the account and the currently logged in user is displayed. Furthermore the Marketing Cloud applications are shown along with the information if they are provisioned in this account and the current user is allowed to access them.
> (Source: [Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Developer Tools (Google Chrome Extension) - Product Website](https://markus.codes/sfmc-chrome-devtools))

**This is how the interface of the chrome extension displays the account type:**
[image: Marketing Cloud Developer Tools]

As this is just an intercepted API-answer, I can't ensure that this is always an appropriate answer. To have a definitive answer, you should look at the contract or get back to the account executive.

However, the values match the AccountTypeEnum values of the SOAP API. Using the following table (taken from [AccountTypeEnum documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/accounttypeenum.htm)) you can identify what edition this corresponds to:

```
| Name               | Data Type   | Description                                  |
|--------------------|-------------|----------------------------------------------|
| BUSINESS_UNIT      | Enumeration | Indicates a business unit account type       |
| CHANNEL_CONNECT    | Enumeration | Indicates a enterprise account type          |
| CONNECT            | Enumeration | Indicates an advanced account type           |
| DOTO_MEMBER        | Enumeration | Indicates an on-your-behalf account type     |
| ENTERPRISE_2       | Enumeration | Indicates an enterprise 2.0 account type     |
| EXACTTARGET        | Enumeration | Indicates a core account type                |
| LP_MEMBER          | Enumeration | Indicates a lock-and-publish account type.   |
| None               | Enumeration | Default response type for AsyncResponseType. |
| PRO_CONNECT        | Enumeration | Indicates a reseller account type            |
| PRO_CONNECT_CLIENT | Enumeration | Indicates a reseller client account type     |
```

You can also retrieve the AccountType-value via the SOAP-API:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24440876" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>ccc</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">ccc</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>Account</ObjectType>
                <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>Name</Properties>
                <Properties>ID</Properties>
                <Properties>EditionID</Properties>
                <Properties>AccountType</Properties>                
                <Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                    <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>GM_DLEAR_123</Value>
                </Filter>
                <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

See [Retrieving Account Object Using The CustomerKey Attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_account_object_using_the_partnerkey_attribute.htm) for more information.

Comment: Wow you are a **Champ!**

Comment: @markus slabina, to my knowledge this is not the same. I am not sure that Enterprise_2 refers to the edition (basic, corporate, enterprise) purchased by the system's customer, but to the underlying system architecture being an "Enterprise 2.0" system, which to my knowledge is unconnected. You could be an enterprise 2.0 system running a corporate edition.

here the docs explain enterprise 1.0 vs. enterprise 2.0:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_compare_enterprise_functionality.htm&type=5


to be sure, I'd have the system owner check their contract for the edition purchased

Comment: Hi Jonas, I'm not entirely sure about the significance of this account type response, as this is just an intercepted API-answer, that isn't documented by Salesforce. From the values I received on the different instances I worked on this is just what I assumed it means as it did match the purchased editions. But yes, to have a definitive answer, one should look at the contract or get back to the account executive.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusSlabina  and Jonas.... I accept this as complete and best answer :)

Comment: @MarkusSlabina what is the meaning of ACCOUNT_TYPE: BUSINESS_UNIT?

Comment: @eeadev This means that you are currently in a child Business Unit (BU) of a Marketing Cloud Account. For more Information on BUs check out the following documentation article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_business_units.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Answer (score 6):

You can use this Chrome extension to get your org's info:

[Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-marketing-clou/bkmmmgaljahinmpijhdggabkdngpadbn)

> To use this extension, open the Chrome Developer Tools when using
>   Salesforce Marketing Cloud and switch to the "Marketing Cloud"-tab.

PS: if it shows nothing, try refreshing the page.

See image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: You welcome, don't forget to accept this answer if it helped resolve your issue..