# How to know my account type? Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, account

I have access to a MC org and I would like to know if the tenant types.
How to know my account type?
I cannot find it under setup.
Sorry for the dummy question but I am new to MC.

Thank you

Comment: For more details: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280924/how-do-i-know-the-marketing-cloud-edition-which-i-am-logged-into/280930#280930

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is a dumb question since the information isn't readily available in the platform, I have wandered in the beginning too.

The easiest way that I can think of is a chrome extension that can provide account type and other information.

It's called "[Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-marketing-clou/bkmmmgaljahinmpijhdggabkdngpadbn)" from Markus.

here is a screenshot reference as an example:

[image]

Please follow the instruction in the tool for the operation.

Also, to have a definitive answer, you should look at the contract or get back to the account executive.

Alternatively, you can leverage the [API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_account_object_using_the_partnerkey_attribute.htm) to retrieve the account details too.