# Marketing Cloud - determine edition

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've wondered how to know whether my org's edition is enterprise or corporate.

I've searched for it, and found out there's 2 ways getting edition info.
here's the question link that I referenced ([How do I know the Marketing Cloud Edition, which I am logged into?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280924/how-do-i-know-the-marketing-cloud-edition-which-i-am-logged-into/280931#280931))

1. via chrome extension named Marketing Cloud Developer tool, but It's not available anymore I guess cause there isn't any marketing cloud developer tool in chrome web store.
2. via SOAP API, but I'm not used to SOAP API, so I don't know how to use this API at all.
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_account_object_using_the_partnerkey_attribute.htm

Could anyone tell me how to get org's edition information other than SOAP API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Marketing cloud doesn't expose edition, you can log a case with salesforce to know edition or reach out to your account executive, apart form above mentioned options.

Comment: I see. I'll ask to salesforce support.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, Marketing cloud doesn't expose edition.

To know about MC edition 1. You can log a case with salesforce and know edition 2. Reach out to your account executive or review account contract details(org contract signing).  Will include more if I come across any other.